# Hide UISearchBar in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I want to have the UISearchBar scrolled out of view when the UIView loads, but have it available when the user drags the table down. Looks something like this:
[screen with bar hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWNF6.png)

I tried `tableViewscrollToRowAtIndexPath:` in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`, but no luck. I also tried the same with `scrollToTop()`.

I've added [the project on gitHub](https://github.com/glowcap/HideSearchBar). If anyone can take a look and help me sort this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

*EDIT* 
Leo's answer works great when the list is full, but how can I achieve the same result when the table is empty or has only a few items? Should I just apply something like

`if tblSearchResults.count > i {
    bar.hidden}`

or is there a less hacky way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `contentOffset` in `viewDidLoad`

```
 self.tblSearchResults.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,50.0)
```

Sceenshot

[image]

Note,the shapeLayer you added to searchBar is a little out of bounds.So you may need to adjust the path of ShapeLaye

Comment: Thanks, Leo. It worked perfectly. The only issue I have now is that it doesn't work when the table isn't populated with more content than can fit the bounds of the view. See my edit to the original question for more details.